# Particle density in k-space

Tags: solid-state-physics, fourier-transform, density

### Question:

Given a many particle wave function $|\Psi\rangle$, how can I calculate the occupation numbers in k-space?

### Setup:

I have a 1D chain of molecules which contains 4 sites per unit cell. Let's say I have $N$ of this unit cells (so in total $4N$ sites). I can write the wave function of electron $n$ as
 $$|\phi_n\rangle=\sum_{j=1}^N \sum_{\beta=1}^4 \sum_\sigma |\alpha_{\beta,\sigma,j} \rangle A_{\beta, \sigma, j,n},$$ where the $A_{\beta, \sigma, j,n}(t)$ are the *time dependent* probability amplitudes of the oribitals $|\alpha_{\beta,\sigma,j}\rangle$. The index $\sigma$ labels the spin of the electrons.

The many particle wave function is now given by $$|\Psi\rangle = \left(\prod_{n=1}^{N_e} \sum_{j=1}^N \sum_\sigma \sum_{\beta=1}^4 \hat{c}^\dagger_{\beta,\sigma,j} A_{\beta, \sigma, j,n}\right) |\text{vac}\rangle,$$ where the $\hat{c}^\dagger_{\beta,\sigma,j}$ is the usual creation operator: it creates an electron with spin $\sigma$ at site $\beta$ in unit cell $j$.

The Hamiltonian of the system contains some hopping terms between the sites and some energy differences between different spin states, but nothing uncommon. I can now use the Fourier transform of the creation and annihilation operators and plug these into my Hamiltonian. This gives me the k-space representation of my the Hamiltonian and allows me to diagonalize the resulting matrix and to get the bandstructure. As there are four sites per unit cells, I obtain four bands $\omega_m(k)$.

In real space, I can easily calculate the occupation of each site via $$\langle n_{\beta,j}(t)\rangle = \sum_\sigma \sum_{n=1}^{N_e} |A_{\beta,\sigma,j,n}(t)|^2.$$

I now want to link this to occupations in k-space and see, which states are occupied/empty at which time $t$. So using the amplitudes $A_{\beta,\sigma,j,n}(t)$ and some phase factor $e^{i k a}$ (with lattice constant a), how can I find out, which states in k-space are occupied and which not?

### Edit:

I try to use the comment of @By Symmetry to work out an example. Please tell me if I do this correctly.
For simplicity, let us take a chain of dimers: Two sites per unit cell ("1" and "2"), lattice constant $a$ between to unit cells and hopping between nearest neighbours. The Hamiltonian in real space would read
$$H=-t\sum_{j=1}^N [\hat{c}^\dagger_{j,2}\hat{c}_{j,1} + \hat{c}^\dagger_{j,2}\hat{c}_{j+1,1}]+h.c.$$

The Fourier transform of the creation and annihilation operators are given by
$$\hat{c}^\dagger_{j,1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_k \hat{c}^\dagger_{k,1} e^{ikja} \qquad \hat{c}^\dagger_{j,2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_k \hat{c}^\dagger_{k,2} e^{ikja} \\ 
\hat{c}_{j,1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_k \hat{c}_{k,1} e^{-ikja} \qquad \hat{c}_{j,2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_k \hat{c}_{k,2} e^{-ikja}  $$

Inserting this, one can write the Hamiltonian as
$$H=\sum_k \hat{\vec{c}}^\dagger_k H_k \hat{\vec{c}}_k$$ with matrix $H_k$ and vectors $\hat{\vec{c}}^\dagger_k= (\hat{c}^\dagger_{k,1},\hat{c}^\dagger_{k,2})$, $\hat{\vec{c}}_k= (\hat{c}_{k,1},\hat{c}_{k,2})$.

Diagonalizing $H_k$ gives the band structure $$\epsilon = \pm t \sqrt{2+2\cos(ka)}.$$

Now the interesting part: The density in k-space is given by 
$$\langle n_k \rangle = \langle \Psi | \hat{\vec{c}}^\dagger_k \hat{\vec{c}}_k |\Psi \rangle.$$
Is it correct to use the vector $\hat{\vec{c}}^{(\dagger)}_k$ here?

Let us now say, I have only two dimers, i.e. 4 sites in total and two electrons. Let us further assume that $|\Psi\rangle$ has the form 
$$|\Psi\rangle = s_1 |1100\rangle + s_2 |1001\rangle$$
where the $s_i$ are the corresponding Slater determinants (built from the $A$ coefficients) and the state $|1001\rangle$ just means that on the first dimer the first site is occupied and that on the second dimer the second site is occupied.

If I now insert this into the formula for $\langle n_k \rangle $, I get
$$\langle n_k \rangle  = \frac{1}{N} \langle \Psi | \sum_{j_1,j_2} \sum_{\beta=1}^2 \hat{c}^\dagger_{\alpha,j_1} \hat{c}_{\alpha,j_2} e^{ika(j_2-j_1)} |\Psi \rangle \\
 = \frac{1}{2} \Big(|s_1|^2+|s_2|^2 + 2 \text{Re} (s_2^* s_1 e^{-ika})\Big)$$

Is this correct and is there a general expression?

Comment: write down k-space occupation operator in terms of k-space creation/annihilation operators, express k-space creation operators in terms of real space operators, apply $|\Psi\rangle$

Comment: @BySymmetry Please notice my edit. Could you please comment on it?

Comment: Using $\vec{c}^\dagger \vec{c}$ is okay in the particle number operator, because this is just a way to write $c_1^\dagger c_1 + c_2^\dagger c_2$